# chrome \chromium how can i find flash location and save buffered flash with pepper flash?

Tags: bash, flash, google-chrome

i did a little script that save flash videos, it uses lsof , :

```
#create an ARRAY which has flash paths   
    filesarray=($(ls -l  "/proc/$(lsof -n | awk ' /Flash/{print $2 ; exit}')/fd" | awk '/Flash/{print $9}')) 
    echo ${filesarray[@]}

    #create an array for firefox ...
    filesarraytwo=($(ls -l  "/proc/$(lsof -n | awk ' /plugin-co/{print $2 ; exit}')/fd" | awk '/Flash/{print $9}')) 
    echo ${filesarraytwo[@]}
```

now this method doesn't work for chromium , i am not able to find the files in /proc/*/fd/* i guess it's pepper flash that it's quite different from the standard flash so , i would like  just complete this script even for chrome chromium and pepper flash.

i tried even to do this

```
 lsof -n | grep -i flash

chromium- 11658                 sem  mem       REG               8,10  17139808    662709 /usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/libpepflashplayer.so
```

but of course on /proc/11658/fd i have no file that are video files so :S

i guess it's not so simple as i thought and i tried to search on these folder without luck

$HOME/.cache/chromium/Default/Cache/

and

$HOME/.cache/chromium/Default/Media Cache/

in these folders i can see some video files but they are not all that's it's pretty strange

EDIT : I found that for long files there is a weird behavior , at the beginning there the file in $HOME/.cache/chromium/Default/Cache/ but after a while they disappear ... so i guess they change location :S

i am using chromium : Version 34.0.1847.116

anyone has find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

i found this solution [here](https://gist.github.com/flyswatter/7357098)  i will paste down here the same stuff you can find in the link:

How to download streaming video

Streaming just means a download that they don't want you to keep. But Chrome's developer tools make it easy to access what's really going on under the hood.

Open Developer Tools

From the page where you want to download some things, go into your chrome menu to open the developer tools. You can either:

(On a mac): Command-option-J
(On a PC): Control-alt-J
(In your menu on a mac): Open View > Developer > Developer Tools
(On any Chrome machine): The far right menu button, to the right of the URL bar, you can press that, go down to "Tools", then open the "Developer Tools".
Monitor Network Traffic

By clicking the "Network" tab, you'll get a list of all files requested since you opened that tab. Our goal is to isolate the web request that returns the video of your choice. At this point, you can navigate to the video you want, and I'd probably press the "clear" button in the developer tools right before finally pressing the "Play" button on the video, so it can be one of the only transfers you see.

Identify the video transfer

It should be easy to recognize the video transfer: It has a mime type of video, it's a transfer that should take a lot longer than the rest, etc.

Once you've found it, click on the request name, which represents the HTTP request that was sent to the server for the video file.

Identify the Request URL

The first thing in the first tab of the request viewer should be the Request URL in the Headers tab. You can just copy this URL into another window/tab, and now if you right click the video, it should include a Save option, unlike when the whole thing was wrapped in Flash or whatever.

Enjoy!